# How to create an auto task schedule ios notification based on an event with mysql data

Tags: mysql, ios, objective-c, scheduled-tasks

I have a problem related to automatic task scheduling.
Currently i am able to find out when my customer has last credited his account, how am i able to find out whether he will pay anything in the next 3 days?
So if no payment has been made in the next three days for any customer, to automatically alert me preferably by a notification directly to my ipad.

I dont want myself to open the app for checks to be done only when i log in, because then if i jump on my application 6 days later, i could have had a customer that hasnt paid in 6 days when the app should have alerted me on the 3rd day so i could ring my customer up to deal with the matter.

I need to work in this matter due to the structure of my application and business.

I am able to monitor everything else but need some insight on how I can go about doing this. the current notification system inside the phone only fires based on time, and I cannot do interval checks where maybe i could run a background task, if that would work then i would have done it like that but thats not the case.

Pavan

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you should compute the interval of the event that you want and post a wake-up timer that is that period of time from "now."  If you need it through the notification center, then just handle it silently and clear it from the notifications.

Based on the discussion below:

You will need a little bit of server work. APNS looks complicated, but it really has very few moving parts -- especially if it is a private App. What system component is keeping an eye on Amazon? Do you have an App or web server? For example, if I were to poke a record into your system (purchased services) what workflow is triggered to notify Accounting to process an invoice and collections at a later date? Am I making any sense of your system architecture?

Perfect - you are done. You have all the system components you need and the rest is coding. The server app processes the accounts DB and finds new entries. If found, it publishes a record ID to the APNS server (Apple owns this server). You write code to register to receive the push-notification (subscriber). When you get a push, that will wake up your registered app with the record ID (and some other subscription stuff for bookkeeping -- but you are the only subscriber and only subscribing to one DB table -- so you can largely ignore. Now turn around and query based on that record. Done!

Comment: I hav a server that stores all my customers balance, i have my own app as the main user who monitors my customers balances. Then I have another application for my account manager who will accept payments from customers. I need a notification that pops up for any customer that does not pay within 3 days of placing an order on my account managers app without me having to start my app initially.

See this notification should come on my ios screen without me having to touch my phone or open my phone.

I hope that clarifies things a bit, and thanks for posting mobibob

Comment: So you want Push Notification (APNS) to your monitor App on your iPhone -- correct?  Have you looked at Apple's doc to set up the environment?

Comment: Im going to be quite honest with you mobibob, it seemed so difficult to get my head around the APNS document that I didn't understand half ot it let alone how to get it all working. Actually, what I have done though is successfully having my application accept push notifications so that it would be future proof incase i did need to use push notifications for my current problem.

Comment: So mobibob, can we use APNS to do hourly checks against current balance data and the last time they paid on my MySQL database which resides on the amazon EC2 server ? and if the mysql query shows that the last time a payment has been made for a specific customer is greater than 3 days to then say, ok we need to send a push notification with the following details: "customer a, has not paid in the last 3 days"?

Comment: You will need a little bit of server work.  APNS looks complicated, but it really has very few moving parts -- especially if it is a private App.  What system component is keeping an eye on Amazon?  Do you have an App or web server?  For example, if I were to poke a record into your system (purchased services) what workflow is triggered to notify Accounting to process an invoice and collections at a later date?  Am I making any sense of your system architecture?

Comment: Rereading your post -- yes -- do you write the code that issues the SQL query and can push the details (actually a "tickle" and retrieve details on the other side).

Comment: I have created a webserver which allows for orders to be processed whereby balance data gets affected. Also a webservice for collecting payment which again changes the data stored on the database.
I have an app for the front end for my account manager and for myself (you could say director, im just interested when someone doesn't pay on time)

Atm, nothing on the server is automatic, its an input gives output system kind of setup.

input through ipad, then feeds it to the webservice which then communicates with the database and the data then returned to the ipad through the webservice

Comment: So, if the apple server etc can process tasks by calling my webservice directly which will then communicate with my mysql database and return teh data required to establish whether a push notification should be made and sent to me... then great! if not and i would need to do something else, then please do let me know what that is. Thanks mobibob

Comment: Not quite .. APNS is passive.  Publisher (Web App) and Subscriber (mobile App) do all the work and APNS is the conduit to make it event driven, timely and queued if the mobile app is offline (out of service).